# Would Noahides be required to eat kosher meat?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, noachide-laws, blood

Would Noahides be required to eat kosher meat because one of the Noahide laws is not to eat blood?

Since non-kosher meat isn't soaked and salted to get the blood out, wouldn't that by default obligate Noahides to only buy kosher meat if they wanted to eat meat?

Comment: Did you also ask if "People of the Book" were required to ear Halal meat on the Islam stackexchange site?

Answer (score 15):

Your question seems to be predicated on understanding [Bereishit 9:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.9.4?lang=bi&aliyot=0)

> אַךְ־בָּשָׂ֕ר בְּנַפְשׁ֥וֹ דָמ֖וֹ לֹ֥א תֹאכֵֽלוּ׃‏
>
> You must not, however, eat flesh with its life-blood in it.

as a prohibition for Noahides to eat blood.

However, Jewish tradition understands this verse differently. Rambam writes in [Hilchot Melachim 9:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.9.1?lang=bi):

> הוֹסִיף לְנֹחַ אֵבֶר מִן הַחַי שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (בראשית ט, ד) "אַךְ בָּשָׂר בְּנַפְשׁוֹ דָמוֹ לֹא תֹאכֵלוּ"‏
>
> A seventh commandment forbidding the eating of a limb torn from a live animal was added for Noah, as it says, “Even flesh, life is in the blood, do not eat of it” (Genesis 9:4).

So a Noahide may eat non-kosher meat containing blood. The only issue that needs to be taken care of is that the meat must not have been removed from the animal while it was still alive.